# PhoneGap Framework works fine XCode3.2.3 however not working in 4.0

Tags: cordova, xcode4, xcode3.2

Plz help,

I am trying to use 'PhoneGap Framework' for creating webapps for Iphone. I have installed this framework in XCode 3.2 and it simply works fine. But I try same thing in XCode 4.0 it doesn't and I need to complete the same task in XCode 4.0.

Steps which I have done till now to install 'PhoneGap' framework in XCode 4.0:-

1-  I downloaded the 'PhoneGap' framework from 'http://www.phonegap.com/download and installed it on my system. (Tried atleast 5 times)'.

2- But the 'User Template' didn't appeared when creating New Project, So I tried to achieve this using the Command script, which I downloaded it from 'http://blogs.nitobi.com/shazron/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/create_project.sh1.zip'

3- I ran this script using the command './create_project.sh  PhoneGapDemo  /Users/patni/Desktop/' from terminal, But gives the error 
'PhoneGapLib is not installed. Download the iOS PhoneGap installer from http://phonegap.com. Go there now (y/n)?'

4- I don't understand why this error is coming, although I have installed the 'PhoneGap' framework properly, 
     When PhoneGap is installed in my system following files has been created:-
        i-   com.apple.Xcode.plist in the folder '~/Library/Preferences/',
    ii-  'PhoneGapLib' library got created in '~/Documents' folder, &
    iii- XCode template 'PhoneGap' in '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Project Templates/' folder.

Please correct me if I am wrong, or plz let me know is it possible to install & use 'PhoneGap' framework in XCode 4.0.

Waiting for reply,

Thanks,
mobileAppMaster

Answer (score 1):

Download the installer with the new Xcode 4 Template for PhoneGap here: http://blogs.nitobi.com/shazron/2011/05/05/phonegap-xcode-4-template/

Answer (score 0):

There's a known issue with Phonegap and Xcode 4. Looks like you found the command line fix. You may have an easier time with [the service Nitobi created](https://build.phonegap.com/generate), which will generate project files for you specifically for use with Xcode 4.

Comment: Ya I got the command line script to create the PhoneGap project for XCode 4 but it didnt work.... :(

Comment: There's an ongoing discussion in the comments of [Cameron Perry's blog](http://iamcam.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/phonegap-xcode4/). Maybe some additional hints found there can help.